# Splitting an Associative Array/Table

Tags: php, mysql, associative-array

I’m using PHP to output a table based on mysql data. I’m using the following code:

```
$result = $db->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>", "<br>". $row["Name"]. "" .$row["message"]."".$row["timestamp"]."<br>","</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
   }
} else {
   echo "0 results";
}
```

Which produces a table that looks a bit like this:

```
--------------------------------
|Name 1   Message 1   timestamp |
--------------------------------
|Name 1   Message 2   timestamp |
--------------------------------
|Name 2   Message 1   timestamp | 
--------------------------------
|Name 3   Message 1   timestamp |
--------------------------------
|Name 3   Message 2   timestamp |
--------------------------------
|Name 3   Message 3   timestamp |
--------------------------------
```

What I would actually like is something that looks a bit like this:

```
Name 1
--------------------------------
|Message 1   | timestamp        |
--------------------------------
|Message 2   | timestamp        |
--------------------------------

Name 2
---------------------------------
|Message 1   |timestamp         | 
--------------------------------

Name 3
--------------------------------
|Message 1   |  timestamp       |
--------------------------------
|Message 2   |  timestamp       |
--------------------------------
|Message 3   |  timestamp       |
--------------------------------
```

Comment: Update your query using `GROUP BY Name`. Then compare the previous user and if changed make a new section.

Comment: Don't do that. Just add a while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to split name from the rest and only display it when the name changes
on the design you must work a little.

```
$result = $db->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $name = "";
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     
        if ($name == $row["Name"])
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row["message"]."</td><td>".$row["timestamp"]."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td colspan=2>". $row["Name"]. "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            $name = $row["Name"];
        }
     }
} else {
   echo "0 results";
}
```